# How can I insert random values in the rest of the columns

Tags: mysql, database, where-clause, sql-insert, create-table

Im haveing this table and is felling with datas from another table and i need the rest to be random inserted form 0-10 interval

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Spital`.`Chirurgie` (
      `ID Persoanl` INT NOT NULL,
      `Doctor` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `Ore` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `Pacienti tratati` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `ID Produse` INT NULL,
      `Denumire` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `Cantitate` INT NULL,
      `IdDepartament` INT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID Persoanl`),



INSERT INTO `spital`.`chirurgie`
            (`ID Persoanl`,
             `Doctor`,
             `Ore`)
SELECT `ID Angajare`,
       `Asistent/Medic`,
       `Ore lucrate`
FROM   `spital`.`personal` 
where `Specializare` like '%Chirurgie%' and `Asistent/Medic`like '%Medic%' ;
```

This is the inseration code that im using for auto fill the values from the other table.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: i need only some random values for pacient fild, id produs, cantitate, from 0-10 number interval, but i dont know how cand i integrate in where or insert the rand() funtion. or if you know another way of doing this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you following query

```
INSERT INTO `spital`.`chirurgie`
            (`ID Persoanl`,
             `Doctor`,
             `Ore`,
             `Pacienti tratati`,
             `ID Produse`,
             `Cantitate`)
SELECT `ID Angajare`,
       `Asistent/Medic`,
       `Ore lucrate`,
        floor(rand()*10)+1 as `Pacienti tratati`,
        floor(rand()*10)+1 as `ID Produse`,
        floor(rand()*10)+1 as  `Cantitate`
FROM   `spital`.`personal` 
where `Specializare` like '%Chirurgie%' and `Asistent/Medic`like '%Medic%' ;
```

Comment: Well id prod is not working

Comment: Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`spital`.`orl`, CONSTRAINT `fk__Stoc General1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID Produse`) REFERENCES `stoc general` (`ID Produs`))

Comment: In this case i need that the program pick a random id form stock general

Comment: `          INSERT INTO `spital`.`chirurgie`
  (`ID Produse`)
SELECT  
  `ID Produse`
FROM   `spital`.`stoc general` 
where ;`

Comment: BTW i found the solution

Comment: I am glad it helped in your issue.